# Android: Play sound when counter reaches integer (Going UP only)

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

New issue I'm faced with in my app, which is not quite a bug but rather a challenge I'm having trouble with.

So in my app, when a certain level of sound is detected, a counter (which is display in a TextView) begins counting. There's certain tiers (based on DragonBall Z power levels), such as 1 to 300'000, then 300'001 to 30'000'000, and finally 30'000'001 to 15'000'000 currently. When sound is not detected any more, the power level slowly declines.

I have a sound file which I need to play as each tier is reached. So as soon as the counter starts, the sound file should play once. Then when the second tier (300'000) is reached, it plays again.

My conditions are, that the file should only play when the power level is going UP, so from 299'999 to 300'000 it would play. But if the power level dropped from 300'001 to 300'000 the sound should not play. Also, because of the large numbers to reach, the counter doesn't increase by 1, but a much larger number depending on the tier.

For example, to get from 300'000 to 30'000'000 counting 1 at a time would take forever. Unless I was about to count this extremely quickly which would be great, but I'm not sure if that's possible. So in that example, I currently have it counting up by 312'345 (random number for testing) every 100 milliseconds (so 3'123'450 per second).

So I can't simply say...

> if (currentPowerlevel == 300000) {mSounds.play(etc)}

As this exact number is likely to be skipped over due to the count increment. So I tried using...

> if (currentPowerlevel > 300000 && currentPowerlevel < 612344) {mSounds.play(etc)}

Hoping that this would mean the file would only be played once as even if 300'000 exactly were to be reached on the counter, the next count would be 612'345 due the increment amount at that tier. But not only is this messy, and requires a lot of bothersome code changes if making changes to tiers / count speed, but it also seems to still not work properly and plays the file repeatedly.

So I'll post all of the relevant code below and hopefully someone can overcome this challenge! Ideally, I would like the following to be true:

- Counter increases by 1 every count, with adjustable speed to account for large tiers such as 3'000'000 to 15'000'000.
- The sound file can only play when going up in count, but not when going down.
- There is some kind of cooldown, or maximum allowable plays of sound per 10 seconds, to stop the file from being repeated.

  public void countPowerLevel() {

  ```
  // Goku Start
  if (currentAmplitude > 9000 && currentPowerLevel <= 299999) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) + 3123;
  } else if (currentAmplitude <= 8999 && currentPowerLevel <= 299999) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) - 312;
  }

  // Goku Kaioken (300'000)
  if (currentAmplitude > 9000 && currentPowerLevel >= 300000) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) + 312345;
  } else if (currentAmplitude <= 8999 && currentPowerLevel >= 300000 && currentPowerLevel <= 29999999){
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) - 31234;
  }


  // Goku Kaioken x 10 (30'000'000)
  if (currentAmplitude > 9000 && currentPowerLevel >= 30000000) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) + 1512345;
  } else if (currentAmplitude <= 8999 && currentPowerLevel >= 30000000 && currentPowerLevel <= 149999999) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) - 151234;
  }

  // Goku Super Saiyan 1 (150'000'000)
  if (currentAmplitude > 9000 && currentPowerLevel >= 150000000) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) + 8012345;
  } else if (currentAmplitude <= 8999 && currentPowerLevel >= 150000000 && currentPowerLevel <= 799999999) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) - 801234;
  }

  if (currentPowerLevel > 800000000) {
      currentPowerLevel = (currentPowerLevel) - 801234;
  }

  // Stop power from going below 1
  if (currentPowerLevel < 1) {
      currentPowerLevel = 1;
  }

  // Alerts for reaching power level milestones
  TextView textCurrentForm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCurrentForm);
  ImageView imgCurrentForm = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCurrentForm);
  imgCurrentForm.setImageResource(R.drawable.goku);

  // Goku Kaioken (300'000)
  if (currentPowerLevel >= 300000) {
      textCurrentForm.setText("Kaioken!");
      imgCurrentForm.setImageResource(R.drawable.gokukk10);
  }

  // Goku Kaioken x 10 (30'000'000)
  if (currentPowerLevel >= 30000000) {
      textCurrentForm.setText("Kaioken x 10!");
      imgCurrentForm.setImageResource(R.drawable.gokukk100);
  }

  // Goku Super Saiyan 1 (150'000'000)
  if (currentPowerLevel >= 150000000) {
      textCurrentForm.setText("Super Saiyan!");
      imgCurrentForm.setImageResource(R.drawable.gokussj);
  }

  // Trigger sounds per power level
  if (currentPowerLevel > 1 && currentPowerLevel < 4000) {
      mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
  }

  if (currentPowerLevel > 4000 && currentPowerLevel < 10000) {
      mSounds.stop(sndAura01);
  }

  if (currentPowerLevel == 300000) {
      mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
  }
  ```

  }

UPDATE:

Okay I've come up with what I think should work, but for some reason it's not working...

```
// Trigger sounds per power level

// Count amount of times sound has been played
int soundPlayed = 0;

if (currentPowerLevel > 1 && currentPowerLevel <= 299999) {
    if (soundPlayed == 0) {
        mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        soundPlayed = 1;
    }
}

if (currentPowerLevel > 300000 && currentPowerLevel <= 2999999) {
    if (soundPlayed == 1) {
        mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        soundPlayed = 2;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

UPDATE 2:

I worked out why the above code isn't working, that entire block is looping in a handler. So immediately after the soundPlayed integer is set to 1, it's set back to 0 again. Working on the solution now...

Comment: Any code refactoring tips would be appreciated too, as I know it's super messy right now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've solved it.

What I did was I first set an integer variable "soundPlayed" at the beginning of my class:

```
// Count amount of times sound has been played
int soundPlayed = 0;
```

I then changed my sound triggers as follows:

```
if (currentPowerLevel > 1 && currentPowerLevel <= 299999) {
    if (soundPlayed == 0) {
        mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        soundPlayed = 1;
    }
}

if (currentPowerLevel > 300000 && currentPowerLevel <= 2999999) {
    if (soundPlayed == 1) {
        mSounds.play(sndAura01, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        soundPlayed = 2;
    }
}
```

So soundPlayed starts at 0. When the power level is between 1 and 299'999, AND the soundPlayed is equal to 0, the sound will be played and the variable soundPlayed will now be set to 1. This code is triggered every 100 milliseconds (10 times per second) as it is a part of my Runnable Handler. On the second, and every other iteration of the loop, it will check if soundPlayed is 0, which it is not (as it's now 1) and will not play the audio file again.

Then once 300'000 is reached, it will now check if soundPlayed is equal to 1, which it is. It plays the sound file again, and now sets soundPlayed to 2.

I could set it back to 0, but it would mean the sound would play again if the power level fell (declined) back down to 299'999 or lower, which I don't want.

Hopefully this helps anyone else who ever needs to achieve something similar!